# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (cvsnakeimage)

Tags: c++, opencv

```
CvPoint _pointsArray[5];
float _g_alpha;
float _g_beta;
float _g_gamma;
_g_alpha = 0.78f;
_g_beta = 0.28f;
_g_gamma = 0.32f;
_criteria.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER;
_pointsArray[0].x =1;
_pointsArray[0].y =1;
_pointsArray[1].x =1;
_pointsArray[1].y =1;
_pointsArray[2].x =1;
_pointsArray[2].y =1;
_pointsArray[3].x =1;
_pointsArray[3].y =1;
_pointsArray[4].x =1;
_pointsArray[4].y =1;
IplImage* temp;
temp = _inImage->getIplImage();
cvSnakeImage(temp,_pointsArray,5,&_g_alpha,&_g_beta,&_g_gamma,CV_VALUE,win,_criteria,false);
```

the above code always give me this error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((icvSnake8uC1R( data, step, size, points, length, alpha, beta, gamma, coeffUsage, win, criteria, calcGradient ? 2 : 1 )) >= 0) in unknown function, file .\src\snakes.cpp, line 425
```

anyone knows what is the reason for this ?????

thanks.

solved thanks. the problem was that the win had an even size not odd size !

Comment: @ahmed :: can you tell me how to use cvSnakeImage()..If possible can you kindly answer my question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432797/cvsnakeimage-opencv-api-example-documentation)